# Another way for production of positive fusion

Tags: energy, pressure, estimation, hydrogen, fusion

I am wondering why energy positive fusion cannot be produced in the following manner.

Large tank of hydrogen pressurized to such a high a level it would push the limits of current technology.

Electrodes capable of discharging millions of volts.

Is there a voltage/current that would cause the hydrogen to fuse?

Comment: You can't just weld a million-volt electrode onto a highly-pressurized hydrogen tank and expect to generate energy. What about the rest of the reactor?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to fuse hydrogen using electrical acceleration.  However even with inconceivably high pressures, the reaction is inefficient and not self sustaining.  So the total energy that can be harvested from the fusion reaction is less than the electrical energy that is put in.

Answer (score 1):

When you squeeze a gas, its temperature goes up. To squeeze hydrogen gas in a tank hard enough to make it fuse, its temperature climbs so high that long before you got it squeezed enough to trigger fusion, any solid material you could imagine making the tank out of would have instantly vaporized, releasing the pressure.

This means that to create fusion in a lab, you need the fusion bottle walls to consist of something other than ordinary matter. Customarily, this is done by confining the fusion reaction inside a set of extremely powerful magnetic fields, so the fusion reaction cannot come into contact with the actual physical walls of the fusion reactor. This is itself an enormously difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it always comes down to two problems to solve:

1. Accelarate the hydrogen to speeds that allow them to overcome the Coulomb force
2. Make the process efficient by letting it happen often enough

(there is a third option by screening the Coulomb force, but matters are complicated enough)

Solving both problems simultaneously is at the limits of our current technology. You can use high pressure (to cover problem 2) and discharge millions of volts (to cover problem 1) and, leaving aside the technical details, in general it seems possible. But it is still at the limits.

See it in a different way: If you don't discover a completely new physical effect (which is not completely unthinkable!), by now, every possible "normal" technical solution you or I can think of will have been tested and discarded by someone else already.